# Problem with MySQL SUM in Node.js Express Project with EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am currently trying to build a dashboard on my Node.js project. To get an overview of certain values, they should be summed up. My SELECT works fine in my MySQL database, but if I include it in my Node project then I will not get any output.

```
app.get('/dash', function(req, res, next) {
    connection.query("SELECT SUM(g_speicherplatz), SUM(g_spielzeit), SUM(g_kosten) FROM games", function(error, result, fields) {
        if(error) {
            req.flash('error', error)
            res.render('games/g-dash', {
                data: ''
            })
        } else {
            res.render('games/g-dash', {
                data: result,
            })
        }
    })
})
```

EJS Output:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <% if (data) { 
            console.log("Anzahl Datensätze: " + data.length);
            data.forEach(function(dash){ %>
            <div class="card mb-3">
               <h3 class="card-header">Statistiken</h3>
               <h3><%= dash.g_speicherplatz %></h3>
               <h3><%= dash.g_spielzeit %></h3>
               <h3><%= dash.g_kosten %></h3>
            </div>
        <% }) %>
        <% } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding aliases to your query, and then refer to them in your view:

```
SELECT
    SUM(g_speicherplatz) AS g_speicherplatz_sum,
    SUM(g_spielzeit) AS g_spielzeit_sum,
    SUM(g_kosten) QS g_kosten_sum
FROM games;
```

And in the view:

```
<div class="card mb-3">
    <h3 class="card-header">Statistiken</h3>
    <h3><%= dash.g_speicherplatz_sum %></h3>
    <h3><%= dash.g_spielzeit_sum %></h3>
    <h3><%= dash.g_kosten_sum %></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign aliases to the sums.

```
    connection.query("SELECT SUM(g_speicherplatz) AS g_speicherplatz, SUM(g_spielzeit) AS g_spielzeit, SUM(g_kosten) AS g_kosten FROM games", function(error, result, fields) {
```